# How to pass arguments to function and still access event to prevent default

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple function to create an item in a project management app. When submitting a form, I want to call this function which I want to pass an ID into, but I still want to preventDefault on the event.

Here's what my code looks like right now

```js
<form onSubmit={() => addItem(list.id)}>

// And the function
  const addItem = listId => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(listId);
  };
```

I've also tried returning another function within the addItem function like so

```js
  const addItem = listId => {
    return event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      console.log("Add item");
    }
  };
```

I would like to access event but am not sure who to set up the parameters correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the currying and call `addItem` like this :

```
<form onSubmit={addItem(list.id)}>
```

and :

```
const addItem = listId => {
    return event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      console.log("Add item");
    }
  };
```

Or

```
const addItem = listId => event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Add item", listId);
};
```

Comment: This worked great and the second example is very clean. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the event to the handler

```
<form onSubmit={(evt) => addItem(evt, list.id)}>

const addItem = (event, listId) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(listId);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => addItem(list.id, event)}>

// And the function
const addItem = (listId, event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(listId);
};
```

an alternative i used, I like to use an "options" object as the last argument to a function for misc values or functions to use:

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => addItem(list.id, { event })}>

// And the function
const addItem = (listId, { event }) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(listId);
};
```